# XML Deserialization of an XDocument is too slow

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, deserialization

I have a very strange problem. I have SQL Server database which returns huge chunk of XML. In the middle I have .Net C# code. And at the front I have two projects, one is WCF and the other is Console app (for testing only).

Now when I run the code to get the XML from DB and deserialize it using console app, it runs pretty fast. But when I run the same code through WCF, it takes forever to deserialize the XML. I am sure, DB is not the bottleneck here but the Serializer is.

I am using XmlSerializer. I cannot switch to DataContractSerializer because I have lots of XML Attributes to process.

EDIT:

This is the serialization code in a static class:

```
public static T DeSerialize(String xml)
{
    T dto = default(T);

    try
    {
        XDocument parsedXML = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        serializer.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownAttribute);
        serializer.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler(serializer_UnknownElement);
        serializer.UnknownNode += new XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
        serializer.UnreferencedObject += new UnreferencedObjectEventHandler(serializer_UnreferencedObject);

        if (serializer.CanDeserialize(parsedXML.CreateReader()))
        {
                    **--This is where everything gets stuck--**
            dto = (T)serializer.Deserialize(parsedXML.CreateReader());
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return dto;
}
```

Then I have just have a manager, lets say WorkManager which uses this code:

```
Work work = Serialize<Work>.DeSerialize(xml);
```

and the above statement is called from Console app and WCF project.

The interface is :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
Method = "POST",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
UriTemplate = "Work")]
XElement Work(Stream contents);
```

And the implementation is:

```
public XElement Work(Stream contents)
{
     String xml = new StreamReader(contents).ReadToEnd();

     WorkManager workManager = new WorkManager();
     workManager.Work(xml);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your WCF code, specifically the portion where you are doing the serialization, since you believe that is the bottleneck?

Comment: Please see the updated post with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of hints:

1. Get rid of that try/catch block. It's not doing anything for you, since you always `throw;`
2. Don't call CreateReader twice, and use a `using` block:

   ```
   using (var reader = parsedXML.CreateReader()) {
       if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
       {
               **--This is where everything gets stuck--**
           dto = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Much much better. Thanks

Comment: I didn't actually intend to solve your problem! If that solved your problem, then your problem will either be that CreateReader takes a long time (so shouldn't be called twice), or, more likely, that because you weren't disposing the XmlReader, you were holding on to resources. Or, because you created two readers on the same XML, and never disposed of them, they were interfering with each other.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if `using` is what improved the performance. Just not curious enough to try it myself :-)